# Error al ejecutar test con Selenium Grid

Tags: c#, selenium, test, selenium-webdriver, grid

Tengo un problema y es que estoy ejecutando unos test en c# con Selenium Grid y me dan errores tales como timeouts, elementos no encontrados... Lo cual no pasa si lo hago en local, no pasa nada. Llevo mirandolo varios dias cambiando cosas como los tiempos y demas y por mas que miro nose que puede estar pasando.

Los lanzo con el driver de Chrome, y solo tengo una instancia en cada maquina porque me daba problemas al lanzarlos todos de golpe, tambien los tengo puestos en paralelo los test.

Muchas gracias.